# The cost of a single T-shirt.

Tags: word-problem

A T-shirt cost 5 times as much as a singlet, for $800, a trader Can buy 32 singlet than T-shirts. How much does a T-shirt cost?

Comment: Please share your thoughts on the problem and which part of it gives you difficulty so answers may be able to better address them

Comment: Did you mean to say that a trader can buy $32$ *more* singlets than t-shirts?

Comment: As with many word problems, define variables and write equations that gather what you know.  What have you tried?

Comment: I just am confused. I tried it but if I had posted it together with the question, no, I wouldn't have known how to even put them together. But if you guys insist, I will attach my solution to it the next time I post a question. Thanks for your concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Suppose a t-shirt costs $\$x$ each and a singlet costs $\$y$ each.

If a t-shirt costs $k$ times as much as a singlet, then $$x=ky$$

If $\$m$ can buy $A$ t-shirts and $B$ singlets, then
$$Ax+By=m$$

Comment: Yeah, this was the kind of ideal I needed. Thanks for the tip/hint.